# How to call multi table insert in myBatis mapper?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, mybatis

I am using myBatis 3.2.x and have run into a scenario where  I need to do multiple table inserts in one database trip,

I was wondering if I can create a master INSERT sql mapper file which would call these multi table inserts and save me network trips

I am consuming JSON objects from a EMS server and my Turn around time is a bit higher then required.

All suggestions and hints are welcome.

Thanks
VR

Comment: Are you allowed to use other datastructures or sort the list?

Comment: Do you control the entry of items into List A if so, then while entering, you can check for duplicates.

Comment: I will get a List from the caller of these comparab;e objects and I can use any DS or Sort after  that...

Comment: Entry into List is not controlled by me i get the List as an input

Answer (score 3):

Use Collections.sort() to sort and use a simple for cycle to catch doubles, e.g.:

```
Collections.sort(myList);
A previous = null;
for (A elem: myList) {
    if (elem.compareTo(previous) == 0) {
        System.err.println("Duplicate: "+elem);
    }
    previous = elem;
}
```

Comment: Would not this report triplicates two times, and so on?

Comment: It was not defined how to report multiple repetitions. If one wants to report it only once, you can add a 'previous-previous' and skip reporting if previous-previous == previous == current.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the Comparable is consistent with the equals implementation, you can use a Set. You can add each element to a Set using Set.add(..) and use the return value of add to determine if the value was already present in the Set and create either a Set or a List to return.

Note: If you need each duplicate returned only once, you can change the return list to a set.

```
 List<A> duplicates(List<A> myList) {

  Set<A> s = new HashSet<A>();
  List<A> duplicates = new ArrayList<A>(); // change to using a Set if you want to report each duplicate item only once. 
  for (A item: myList) {
    if (!s.add(item)) { 
      duplicates.add(item);
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

An improved version using sorting (to report duplicate elements only once, I assume there are no `null` values in the list):

```
Collections.sort(myList);
A previous = null, elem = null;
for (java.util.Iterator<A> it = myList.iterator; it.hasNext(); elem = it.next()) {
    if (elem.compareTo(previous) == 0) {
        System.err.println("Duplicate: "+elem);
        while (it.hasNext() && (elem = it.next()).compareTo(previous)) {
           //loop through other values
        }
    }
    previous = elem;
}
```

A version using `SortedSet` (probably this is faster a bit): and corrected the same

```
SortedSet<A> set = new TreeSet<>(), duplicates = new TreeSet<>();
for (A a: myList) {
    if (!set.add(a)) {
        duplicates.add(a);
    }
}
return duplicates;//or for (A a: duplicates) System.println("Duplicate: " + a);
```

Comment: shouldn be if (!set.add(a)) ?

Comment: Thanks the second one takes care of all my scenarios ;)

Comment: The sortedset solution creates a new storage, and is very operation heavy by adding to the sorted tree one-by-one. It is not faster to do this way.

Comment: In the first solution, please use java 1.5+ foreach, this horrid manual iterator construct is why aliens won't talk to us!!!11!1!1 :)

Comment: @AgostonHorvath Well, for cache locality the first solution clearly better, so for modern hardware it is probably faster. But both are O(nlogn) worst case (and as we do not sort probably many duplicate elements the second might be O(nlogu), where u is the number of unique elements. So theoretically the second one should be faster when there are many duplicate elements). Regarding foreach: Can you do that efficiently in this case? I cannot.